# Позиционирование текста в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть слайдер и внутри него текст. В компьютерной версии он отображается так как мне нужно, но в мобильной он съезжает вправо и нижний текст с иконками не могу сделать друг под другом.

```css
.sliderr__item .slid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/*END*/

.sliderr {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderr__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sliderr__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.sliderr .date {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}


/* Added: */

.sliderr__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.sliderr__control {
  /* Added: */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Updated: */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  /* The Same: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  background: #5FA467;
  /*
        REMOVED: transform: translateY(-50%);
      */
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderr"><br>
  <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 150px;" class="slid">
        <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #5FA467;">My first text</p><br>
        <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 16px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">My second text</p><br>
        <p style="display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #000;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><span>My User</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="margin-left: 20px;"> 21.08.2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 150px;" class="slid">
        <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #5FA467;">My first text</p><br>
        <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 16px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">My second text</p><br>
        <p style="display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #000;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><span>My User</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="margin-left: 20px;"> 21.08.2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть 3 параграфа текста и мобильной версии нужно чтобы они были в центре, а у меня съезжают и иконки с текстом тоже не друг под другом находятся. Помогите, в чем проблема здесь? Полный код с `JS` тут `https://jsfiddle.net/ofzpnL2k/4/`

Comment: Ну во первых не стоит использовать инлайновые стили, они и мешают частично. Плюс у родителя задана высота жёстко да и для мобильной версии у вас вообще нет стилей они должны меняться через media

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего комментатора. Вы также можете использовать [систему сеток bootstrap](http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) для упрощения.